# ReactiveCocoa: Handling Multiple Unbalanced Keyboard Notifications

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I am building a sample auth view controller with Reactive Cocoa. I know how to setup and receive notifications from the Keyboard in a reactive manner. However, I get unbalanced UP and DOWN notifications. Because of this, I have to setup a BOOL variable to see if if the keyboard has been previously raised but not dropped. Is there a way to do this Reactively? The complete project is [here](https://github.com/rismay/AuthController/blob/master/AuthController/WSMAuthViewController.m).

```
- (void)configureKeyboardAnimations {
CGFloat duration = 0.9, damping = 0.8;
@weakify(self);
[[[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter rac_addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                      object:nil]
  takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal] subscribeNext:^(NSNotification *notification) {
    @strongify(self);
    if (!self.tableViewOffset) {
        CGRect keyboardRect = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:damping
              initialSpringVelocity:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                         animations:^{
                             self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableView.frame, 0,
                                                                 -CGRectGetHeight(keyboardRect));
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
        self.tableViewOffset = YES; //I need this set immediately not at completion. 
    }
}];

[[[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter rac_addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                      object:nil]
  takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal] subscribeNext:^(NSNotification *notification) {
    @strongify(self);
    CGRect keyboardRect = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:damping
          initialSpringVelocity:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                     animations:^{
                         self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableView.frame, 0,
                                                             CGRectGetHeight(keyboardRect));
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
    self.tableViewOffset = NO; //I need this set immediately not at completion. 
}];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Think I've got a solution for you. May not be the simplest, but it will work and I feel like it's a "ReactiveCocoa" way to solve the problem.

```
RACSignal *keyboardShowSignal = [[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter rac_addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil] takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal];

RACSignal *keyboardHideSignal = [[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter rac_addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil] takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal];

RACSignal *latestNotification = [RACSignal merge:@[keyboardShowSignal, keyboardHideSignal]];
[[[latestNotification map:^id(NSNotification *notification) {
    return notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
}] distinctUntilChanged] subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *rectNumber) {
    // Animate things here with [rectNumber CGRectValue]
}];

RAC(self, tableViewOffset) = [[[latestNotification map:^id(NSNotification *notification) {
    return @([notification.name isEqualToString:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification]);
}] distinctUntilChanged] startWith:@(NO)];
```

The complete project is [here](http://cloud.ashfurrow.com/31270p2S3h05).

Answer (score 2):

I looked further into why I was getting multiple UP notifications. It appears what when you switch focus from a firstResponder that has different auto-correct settings, two UP notifications get sent back to back. One up notification is the original move up and then the next would be an adjustment for the small strip above the keyboard for autocorrect. Once, you realize this, you can basically abstract the math to handle up and down notifications the same way. My final solution MERGED the up and down keyboard signals into one signal. This has got to be the shortest way to handle keyboard notifications I have ever seen.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter;
@weakify(self);
[[[RACSignal merge:@[[center rac_addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil],
                     [center rac_addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil]]]
  takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal] subscribeNext:^(NSNotification *notification) {
    @strongify(self);
    CGRect keyboardRectBegin = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect keyboardRectEnd = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat offset = CGRectGetMinY(keyboardRectEnd) - CGRectGetMinY(keyboardRectBegin);
    NSTimeInterval duration = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.8f
          initialSpringVelocity:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                     animations:^{
                         self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableView.frame, 0, offset);
                     } completion:nil];
}];
```